# Newman: How to parse JSON

Tags: json, newman

I am trying to parse one of my API JSON responses using Newman for component test execution, but unfortunately, I am getting `Json.parse error`, which is quite strange.

Below is my JSON structure:

```
{
    "access_token": "TESTOKEN",
    "token_type": "Treat",
    "expires_in": 374
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty Easy.

Old format that i still use.

In Your tests section write this code:

```
var myBody = JSON.parse(responseBody)
cosnole.log(myBody)
```

then doing whatever you want with it

But make sure you are getting exactly json format response. Or its presence

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to get the `access_token` and set this as a variable, to use it future requests:

`pm.environment.set('token', pm.response.json().access_token)`

You could of course do the same for any of the other values within the response.